# userLocation so different to CLLocation

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit, core-location

I am using CoreLocation to plot my lat/long. This is displayed as Homer in the attached picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IPQX.png). I have `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` set:

```
self.locMgr.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

When I enable userLocation on the map (blue dot) there appears to be a pretty big difference between the accuracies. The blue dot is alot more accurate to my actual location.

1. How can I improve CoreLocations accuracy to position my MKAnnotations closers to my actual location?
2. Why am I getting this inaccuracy? userLocation is wifi based while Homer is GPS?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How are you adding Homer to the map?  In what method?  Before adding Homer, you may need to check the user location timestamp and/or horizontalAccuracy.

Comment: is the wifi on? are you in China?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

China offsets the GPS for annotations other then users current location. More information can be found here:

http://www.sinosplice.com/life/archives/2013/07/16/a-more-complete-ios-solution-to-the-china-gps-offset-problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement mapView:didUpdateUserLocation and, within that, set your annotation location to equal the mapView's userLocation.
2. I'm not entirely sure, but I assume it's probably due to mapview using a private framework for location.